# Removing spaces from array input by user

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, spaces

I want to remove any spaces from the user input and give the result back on the screen. So far, the following is my working solution. I haven't noticed any errors yet. Since I'm pretty new to C and programming in general, my question is: Is there something I can do better? Anything to optimize or something? I appreciate any tips from you guys since you are probably a lot more experienced than I am. So, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PUFFERGROESSE 100
#define ERROR 1
#define OK 0

int main(){

    char stringPuffer[PUFFERGROESSE];
    printf("Please enter some words:"); fflush(stdout);
    if(fgets(stringPuffer, PUFFERGROESSE, stdin) == NULL){
        printf("Unable to read.\n");
        return ERROR;
    } else {
        char endString[PUFFERGROESSE];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < PUFFERGROESSE; i++, j++) {
            if (stringPuffer[i] != ' ' ) {
                endString[j] = stringPuffer[i];
            } else {
                j--;
            }
        }


        printf("Without spaces your input looks like that: %s", endString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions regarding code efficiency, as opposed to not-working code, are best asked at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that website!

Comment: instead of messing around with `j` you could more simply do `endString[j++] = stringPuffer[i];` but don't forget to terminate the string if you use `strlen`

Comment: You could get rid of `endString` all together: `for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(stringPuffer); i++) if (' ' != stringPuffer[i]) stringPuffer[j++] = stringPuffer[i];` Then add an '\0' at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the `for` loop condition is `i < PUFFERGROESSE`. Inside this loop, you access `stringPuffer` using the loop index.

Now, `stringPuffer` being an uninitialized automatic local variable and with a sufficiently small input, a strict check like `i < PUFFERGROESSE` will cause access to uninitialized memory of `stringPuffer`, creating [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can make use of [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) after taking the user input.

Another note, `int main()` is better as `int main(void)`, at least.

NITPICK: why's the `OK` defined, if not used?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement that in my code later that day.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. Initialize `endString` to all zeros; that way you won't have to worry about string termination issues later on:

   ```
   char endString[PUFFERGROESSE] = {0};
   ```

   Instead of looping while `i` is less than `PUFFERGROESSE`, loop until you see the end of the string:

   ```
   for( int i = 0, j = 0; stringPuffer[i] != 0; i++ )
   ```

   Also, only increment `j` when you write the non-space character, rather than incrementing it unconditionally and then having to decrement it when you see a space:

   ```
   if ( !isspace( stringPuffer[i] ) )
     endString[j++] = stringPuffer[i];
   ```

So basically, that code reduces to:

```
char endString[PUFFERGROESSE] = {0};

for (int i = 0, j = 0; stringPuffer[i] != 0; i++) {
  if ( !isspace( stringPuffer[i] ) ) {
      endString[j++] = stringPuffer[i];
  }
}
```